# the data is not properly receiving?

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have developed an android app that sends the sensor data to lamp server for sending data using services in background and for backed i have used php. when i run the app the background services starts i am getting the data successful insertion message from server the lamp server rows are updating but the values are not storing. null values are storing please help me out to find where is problem in the code?

```
public void data() throws JSONException {
final String LIGHTSENS, LIGHTDATA, TEMPSENSOR, TEMPDATA, AMBTEMPSENSOR, AMBTEMDATA, PRESSURESENS, PRESSUREDATA, LATTITUDE, LONGITUDE, DATE, TIME;
        LIGHTSENS = String.valueOf(lr1);
        LIGHTDATA = String.valueOf(ld1);
        TEMPSENSOR = String.valueOf(tr1);
        TEMPDATA = String.valueOf(td1);
        AMBTEMPSENSOR = String.valueOf(atr1);
        AMBTEMDATA = String.valueOf(atd1);

        PRESSURESENS = String.valueOf(pr1);
        PRESSUREDATA = String.valueOf(pd1);
        LATTITUDE = String.valueOf(la);
        LONGITUDE = String.valueOf(lg);


StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Server_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(sens.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

                Toast.makeText(sens.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError, AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("LIGHTSENS", LIGHTSENS);
                params.put("LIGHTDATA", LIGHTDATA);
                params.put("TEMPSENSOR", TEMPSENSOR);
                params.put("TEMPDATA", TEMPDATA);
                params.put("AMBTEMPSENSOR", AMBTEMPSENSOR);
                params.put("AMBTEMDATA", AMBTEMDATA);
                params.put("PRESSURESENS", PRESSURESENS);
                params.put("PRESSUREDATA", PRESSUREDATA);
                params.put("LATTITUDE", LATTITUDE);
                params.put("LONGITUDE", LONGITUDE);


                return  super.getParams();
                //params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                //params.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));

                //return params;

            }

        };

        //Mysingleton.getmInstance(sens.this).addTorequestque(stringRequest);


       // RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

       // RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: why you return super.getParams();

Comment: even if  I put return.params; I am not able to recive just kind of I tried it. you can see i commented that code line.

Comment: Please debug your service first to ensure you are receiving null... The chances are your service have a problem inserting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    private void data() {

        final String LIGHTSENS, LIGHTDATA, TEMPSENSOR, TEMPDATA, AMBTEMPSENSOR, AMBTEMDATA, PRESSURESENS, PRESSUREDATA, LATTITUDE, LONGITUDE, DATE, TIME;
        LIGHTSENS = String.valueOf(lr1);
        LIGHTDATA = String.valueOf(ld1);
        TEMPSENSOR = String.valueOf(tr1);
        TEMPDATA = String.valueOf(td1);
        AMBTEMPSENSOR = String.valueOf(atr1);
        AMBTEMDATA = String.valueOf(atd1);

        PRESSURESENS = String.valueOf(pr1);
        PRESSUREDATA = String.valueOf(pd1);
        LATTITUDE = String.valueOf(la);
        LONGITUDE = String.valueOf(lg);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Server_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(sens.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(sens.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("LIGHTSENS", LIGHTSENS);
                params.put("LIGHTDATA", LIGHTDATA);
                params.put("TEMPSENSOR", TEMPSENSOR);
                params.put("TEMPDATA", TEMPDATA);
                params.put("AMBTEMPSENSOR", AMBTEMPSENSOR);
                params.put("AMBTEMDATA", AMBTEMDATA);
                params.put("PRESSURESENS", PRESSURESENS);
                params.put("PRESSUREDATA", PRESSUREDATA);
                params.put("LATTITUDE", LATTITUDE);
                params.put("LONGITUDE", LONGITUDE);
                Log.d(TAG, "@@@ params:" + params + " URL:" + Server_url);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(sens.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```